# Se puede restringir el acceso a un asuario en php por medio de REMOTE_ADDR?

Tags: php

mi duda es si puedo utilizar "REMOTE_ADDR" para validar un inicio de sesión en php ademas del usuario y la contraseña, mi duda es si esa ip obtenida cambia o siempre es la misma?

Este es el comando que utilizo y me arroja una ip.

```
{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
```

Comment: la dirección IP cambiará según la red y/o dispositivo que use el usuario para ingresar a tu sitio web, por lo tanto excepto que tengas certeza que siempre accederá desde el mismo punto yo no la consideraría opción.

Comment: Hola, pues no es un sitio web publico, el usuario siempre va acceder desde  un pc u otro dispositivo pero en la misma red local